# How to delay all the calls to any method of a javascript object until the object is initialized?

Tags: javascript

Suppose this simple piece of code:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

function MyClass(db) {
    var self = this;
    this._initError = new Error("MyClass not initialized");

    db.loadDataAsyncronously(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            self._initError =err;
        } else {
            self._initError = null;
            self.data = data;
        }
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.getA = function(cb) {
    if (this._initError) {
        return cb(this._initError);
    }
    return cb(null, this.data.a);
};

MyClass.prototype.getB = function(cb) {
    if (this._initError) {
        return cb(this._initError);
    }
    return cb(null, this.data.b);
};


var db = {
    loadDataAsyncronously: function(cb) {
        // Emulate the load process from disk.
        // Data will be available later
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(null, {
                a:"Hello",
                b:"World"
            });
        },1000);
    }
};

var obj = new MyClass(db);
obj.getA(function (err, a) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("a: " + a);
    }
});

obj.getB(function (err, b) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("a: " + b);
    }
});
```

This gives an error because obj is not initialized when getA and getB methods are called. I would like that any method called before the object is initialized, be delayed automatically until the class finish its initialization.

One way to solve it is this way:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

function MyClass(db) {
    var self = this;
    self._pendingAfterInitCalls = [];

    db.loadDataAsyncronously(function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            self.data = data;
        }
        self._finishInitialization(err);
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.getA = function(cb) {
    this._waitUntiliInitialized(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        return cb(null, this.data.a);
    });
};

MyClass.prototype.getB = function(cb) {
    this._waitUntiliInitialized(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        return cb(null, this.data.b);
    });
};

MyClass.prototype._finishInitialization = function(err) {
    this._initialized=true;
    if (err) {
        this._initError = err;
    }
    this._pendingAfterInitCalls.forEach(function(call) {
        call(err);
    });
    delete this._pendingAfterInitCalls;
};

MyClass.prototype._waitUntiliInitialized = function(cb) {
    var bindedCall = cb.bind(this);
    if (this._initialized) {
        return bindedCall(this._initError);
    }
    this._pendingAfterInitCalls.push(bindedCall);
};


var db = {
    loadDataAsyncronously: function(cb) {
        // Emulate the load process from disk.
        // Data will be available later
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(null, {
                a:"Hello",
                b:"World"
            });
        },1000);
    }
};

var obj = new MyClass(db);
obj.getA(function (err, a) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("a: " + a);
    }
});

obj.getB(function (err, b) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("a: " + b);
    }
});
```

But it seems to me a lot of overhead to be written for each class following this pattern.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this functionality?

Does exist any library to simplify this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Preparing this question, came to my head what probable would be a good answer. The idea is to use the concept of a factory function. The code above would be rewritten this way.

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

function createMyClass(db, cb) {
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj._init(db, function(err) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, obj);
    });
}

function MyClass() {
}

MyClass.prototype._init = function(db, cb) {
    var self=this;
    db.loadDataAsyncronously(function(err, data) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        self.data = data;
        cb();
    });
};

MyClass.prototype.getA = function(cb) {
    if (this._initError) return cb(this._initError);
    cb(null, this.data.a);
};

MyClass.prototype.getB = function(cb) {
    if (this._initError) return cb(this._initError);
    cb(null, this.data.b);
};

var db = {
    loadDataAsyncronously: function(cb) {
        // Emulate the load process from disk.
        // Data will be available later
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(null, {
                a:"Hello",
                b:"World"
            });
        },1000);
    }
};

var obj;
createMyClass(db,function(err, aObj) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    obj=aObj;

    obj.getA(function (err, a) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("a: " + a);
        }
    });

    obj.getB(function (err, b) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("a: " + b);
        }
    });
});
```

I share this Q/A because I thing it can be interesting to some body else. If you thing there exist better solutions, libraries to handle this situations, or any other idea, I will appreciate it.

Comment: I rather doubt you're accomplishing anything with all the return statements inside your async callbacks.  Those return values are just going back into the async infrastructure, not back to the original caller.

Comment: Agree, I just removed the return.

Answer (score 1):

The usual strategy here is to NOT use any async operation from a constructor.  If an object needs an async operation in order to initialize it, then you use one of two options:

1. The async portion of the initialization is done in an `.init(cb)` method that must be called by the creator of the object.
2. You use a factory function that takes a callback that is called when the async portion of the operation has completed (like your proposed answer).

If you create a lot of these, perhaps the factory function makes sense because it saves you a little repeated code.  If you don't create a lot of them, I prefer the first option because I think it makes it a lot clearer in the code exactly what is happen (you create an object and then you initialize it asynchronously and then the code continues only when the async operation has completed).

For the first option, it could look like this:

```
function MyClass(...) {
    // initialize instance variables here
}

MyClass.prototype.init = function(db, callback) {
    var self = this;
    db.loadDataAsyncronously(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            self._initError = err;
        } else {
            self._initError = null;
            self.data = data;
        }
        callback(err);
    });
}


// usage
var obj = new MyClass(...);
obj.init(db, function(err) {
    if (!err) {

        // continue with rest of the code that uses this object
        // in here

    } else {
        // deal with initialization error here
    }
});
```

---

Personally, I would probably use a design using promises so the calling code could look like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass(...);
obj.init(db).then(function() {
    // object successfully initialized, use it here
}, function(err) {
    // deal with initialization error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Promise internally in MyClass and have all functions wait for the promise to complete before proceeding.

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: You can't return a promise from a constructor.  The constructor has to return the object.  That's the issue here.

Comment: MyClass can internally store the promise and all functions can proceed when the promise resolves or rejects.

Comment: Why don't you show how that would work and how the callers of the other functions would know when the other functions were done and how you'd propagate and handle errors from the initialization.  I really don't think you should try to hide the async behavior from the caller.  The caller needs to know when something is async so they can program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the precondition into the functions:

```
function injectInitWait(fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        this._waitUntiliInitialized(function(err) {
            if (err) return args[args.length - 1](err);
            fn.apply(this, args);
        });
    } 
}

injectInitWait(MyClass.prototype.getA);
injectInitWait(MyClass.prototype.getB);
```

That being said, your factory approach would be superior.